# Cannot get div to center

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I have tried everything to get a div of dynamic width (highlightsContainer) to center within its parent. I think it has something to do with the fact that this div takes up 100% of the parent container width, no matter what I do.

I have tried to set it to inline-block, but that does not fix it. Dev Tools still shows it as taking up 100% of the parent container width. The children of `.highlightsContainer` are not forcing it to this width.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="highlightsContainerWrapper">
   <div class="highlightsContainer">
       <a href="#video">
          <div class="highlightEntry">
              <img src="../img/portfolio/lr/lr-highlight-1.png" />
              <div class="highlightLabel">Mobile Site</div>
           </div>
       </a>
       <a href="#email">
           <div class="highlightEntry">
              <img src="../img/portfolio/lr/lr-highlight-2.png" />
              <div class="highlightLabel">Video Gallery</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#social">
            <div class="highlightEntry">
               <img src="../img/portfolio/lr/lr-highlight-3.png" />
               <div class="highlightLabel">jQuery Modals</div>
             </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#blog">
             <div class="highlightEntry">
                <img src="../img/portfolio/lr/lr-highlight-4.png" />
                <div class="highlightLabel">SEO</div>
             </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.highlightsContainerWrapper {
    float: left;
}

.highlightsContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.highlightEntry {
    width: 18%;
    margin: 3% 1%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #fcfbe7;
}
```

Comment: There are two main concepts to understand here; 1. If an element is display: block; it takes up 100% of the parent container, and 2. If an element is display inline-block than it can no longer accept margin: auto; since it is inline in that respect. the elements width is dependent on its children instead of its parent. therefore its starting position relative to its parent is determined with text-align

Comment: I am little bit confused but do you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/YmM4d/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
.highlightsContainerWrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Works for dynamically generated content. You won't have to set a width on `.highlightsContainer`

[**Working jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YmM4d/1)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous comment, this could also work as well without having to have the width be 100 percent each time if you don't want it to be.

```
.highlightsContainerWrapper {
   float: left;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Then you can make the width whatever you want it to be.

Hoped that helped you center the div

Comment: See the link I just posted. I removed `width:100%` and it no longer centers it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see now. If you change the width then it won't consider dynamic content that he inputs. Thanks for the correction. I tried it right now as well and just saw that you're right.